# Proper Sequelize flow to avoid duplicate rows?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize in my node js server. I am ending up with validation errors because my code tries to write the record twice instead of creating it once and then updating it since it's already in DB (Postgresql).

This is the flow I use when the request runs:

```
const latitude = req.body.latitude;
var metrics = await models.user_car_metrics.findOne({ where: { user_id: userId, car_id: carId } }) 

if (metrics) {
    metrics.latitude = latitude;
    .....
} else {
    metrics = models.user_car_metrics.build({
        user_id: userId,
        car_id: carId,
        latitude: latitude
        ....
    });
}

var savedMetrics = await metrics();
return res.status(201).json(savedMetrics);
```

At times, if the client calls the endpoint very fast twice or more the endpoint above tries to save **two new rows** in `user_car_metrics`, with the same `user_id` and `car_id`, both FK on tables `user` and `car`.

I have a constraint:

`ALTER TABLE user_car_metrics DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS user_id_car_id_unique, ADD CONSTRAINT user_id_car_id_unique UNIQUE (car_id, user_id);`

Point is, there can only be one entry for a given `user_id` and `car_id` pair.

Because of that, I started seeing validation issues and after looking into it and adding logs I realize the code above adds duplicates in the table (without the constraint). If the constraint is there, I get validation errors when the code above tries to insert the duplicate record.

Question is, how do I avoid this problem? How do I structure the code so that it won't try to create duplicate records. Is there a way to serialize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a unique constraint then you can use `upsert` to either insert or update the record depending on whether you have a record with the same primary key value or column values that are in the unique constraint.

```js
await models.user_car_metrics.upsert({
        user_id: userId,
        car_id: carId,
        latitude: latitude
        ....
    })
```

See [upsert](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-upsert)

> PostgreSQL - Implemented with ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE. If update data contains PK field, then PK is selected as the default conflict key. Otherwise, first unique constraint/index will be selected, which can satisfy conflict key requirements.

Comment: makes sense. I'll test it out. thanks

Comment: ok, so, upsert only returns a boolean (true) if things went through fine. Is there a way to get the record back as part of the upset call? I am asking because I have logic that also depends on the possible existing record data. Regardless I will mark this as the correct answer because it answers the question. Thank you.

Comment: As `returns an array with two elements, the first being the new record and the second being true if it was just created or false if it already existed (except on Postgres and SQLite, which can't detect this and will always return null instead of a boolean).` says you cannot figure out if a record is new or not in case of PostgreSQL

Comment: interesting, I log that out and I only get a boolean. console.log(` metrics: ${JSON.stringify(metrics)}`). logs 'true' the first time and then 'false' the rest of the time (the record already existed). I don't see any record...

Comment: ok, I was using an 'invalid' version. Needed to update the module. 